# How to login as an existing user in django shell

Tags: django

In django shell, I want to debug a specific api call, and for the resource to work, one should be logged in.

```py
from django.test import  Client
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl

client = Client()
client.login(username='my_username', password='my_password')
# I also tried client.force_login() without success

url_data = urlsplit(url)
r = client.get(path=url_data.path, data=parse_qsl(url_data.query))

# r is <HttpUnauthorized status_code=401, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**edit:** I'm talking about a real environment (pre-production) with real credentials

How do I login properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
    # A backend authenticated the credentials
else:
    # No backend authenticated the credentials
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: That's the same thing that is called by `client.login()` and it doesn't work